# How do I get the special skin from the Potato Sack pack for Portal 2?

Tags: portal-2

In the description for purchasing the Potato Sack pack of games, it was stated (bold mine):

> Plus, if you buy this pack (or have all 13 of these games in your account) you get a potato hat in Team Fortress 2! (Potato hat available after April 5th) and **a special skin in Portal 2 co-op**.

I purchased the pack, but when I go to the Robot Enrichment screen, there aren't any new skins for Atlas or P-Body. I also searched the ingame store to no avail.

Where, when or how can I get my special skin from preordering?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a bit of a misunderstanding. The 'skin' you receive from the potato sack is the flag for the game you played the most. For example, I got a BIT.TRIP.BEAT flag. This is weird, seeing as Portal 2 supports actual skins, but this is what Valve said.

Comment: Do you have a source for Valve's statement?

Comment: @FallenAngelEyes Unfortunately not. This has been sent by Steam Support to members of the Steam Forums, but no public announcement has been made to clear this up.

Answer (score 8):

You have already done what is necessary, now you have only to wait that Valve distributes the skins to all accounts.

I think that is only a matter of time, probably they are busy with a lot of support stuff now. The important is, at the moment, all players are in the same situation and as I know no one have received them yet.

Comment: Well, only answer so far!

Answer (score 0):

They will distribute the skins soon, and you Also got a flag for the game of the potato sack you played the most. the flag CANNOT be the "skin" because valve said the potato sack skin would be "EXCLUSIVE" and the flags are available in the ingame store. Just wait. trading has not come out yet, and the skins will probably be distributed with that update.

Comment: Ask Steam support yourself. They've told me and numerous other people that the flag is the skin you get for the potato pack.